# Firebase cloud function returning unauthenticated right after login

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following problem. I have implemented a Firebase cloud function that returns a user profile from the Firestore. My cloud functions require you to be logged in to Firebase in order to be able to query them.

Now, in my app I implemented that on `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged` a cloud function for getting a user profile is being called. However, when I log in to the app, the triggered call returns PlatformException with reason UNAUTHENTICATED, although in a line before that I check for current user with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` and I get a correct and valid uid. There are no logs in the Firebase involving this function, only for other functions which all succeed and are also called on `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged`.

Here is the cloud function, which is basically really simple:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export default functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.info(`[api-userProfile] called with userUid=${data.userUid}`);

  const user: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("userProfiles")
    .where("userUid", "==", data.userUid)
    .get();

  if (user.docs.length === 1) {
    console.info(
      `[api-userProfile] returning user for userUid=${data.userUid}`
    );
    return user.docs[0].data();
  }

  console.info(`[api-userProfile] could not find userUid=${data.userUid}`);
  return null;
});
```

And this is where I call it:

```dart
final _disposeBag = CompositeSubscription();
  final userProfile = BehaviorSubject<UserProfile>();

final _userProfilesFn =
      CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(functionName: "api-userProfile");

UserProfileStore() {
  _disposeBag.add(FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged
      .map((v) => v != null ? v : throw "")
      .handleError((v) => userProfile.add(null))
      .asyncMap((v) {
        print(v.uid); // here the correct uid is printed
        return _userProfilesFn.call({"userUid": v.uid});
      })
      .map((v) => v as Map)
      .map((v) => UserProfile.fromJson(v))
      .addTo(userProfile)
      .listen((_) {}));
}
```

And the error thrown is (first line is the uid of the logged in user):

```
I/flutter ( 9370): DXrcqtU34Dh8UfZYnsNdxn31hqx2
E/flutter ( 9370): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: UNAUTHENTICATED, details: null, message: UNAUTHENTICATED})
E/flutter ( 9370): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:569
E/flutter ( 9370): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:321
E/flutter ( 9370): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9370): #2      MethodChannelCloudFunctions.callCloudFunction 
package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel_cloud_functions.dart:43
E/flutter ( 9370): #3      HttpsCallable.call 
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:33
E/flutter ( 9370): #4      new UserProfileStore.<anonymous closure>
```